# What's inside the UFO Robot Grendizer Manga Kanzenban?

Tags: merchandise, ufo-robot-grendizer

I want to buy a present for an old anime fan and since he likes UFO Robot Grendizer I decided to get him a manga of it. I found something called UFO Robot Grendizer Manga Kanzenban / Complete Edition on eBay. It says that the release date is 2012 but there is no other information.

Does anybody know what's in this book? Is it a collection of old manga chapters or just random artwork? Also, is it drawn by Go Nagai or not? I really appreciate your help...

Comment: Including the actual link would have been apreciated

Answer (score 2):

A kanzenban (完全版) is similar to a viz big edition or 3 in1 edition, or the English equivalent, a omnibus. This means it will contain several chapters in 1 edition of the magazine. This is done to be cheaper in production etc.

If I recall correctly the Kanzenban edition is already the 4th edition, published by Manga Shop. Yet it still contains the original art work of Go Nagai and Yū Okazaki. As do the other 3 versions. All tough there might be some slight change when buying translated version, the french version is known to have allot of changes *(Speaking from experience.. I have a copy over here)*

The kanzenban edition did get released in 2012, and is listed under

**ISBN:     9784775914533 4775914537** or 
**OCLC-nummer:  788225116**